# How do I detect if the spaced bar is typed/Pressed using C# on mac?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keypress

I am writing a program that will do something if the space key is pressed.
I have so far :

```
  Console.WriteLine("Listening for the BIG BUTTON:......... ");
  ConsoleKeyInfo name = Console.ReadKey();
  Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name.KeyChar);

  if(//keyPressed is the spacekey" ){

    Console.WriteLine("Space key is pressed);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Console.WriteLine("Listening for the BIG BUTTON:......... ");
ConsoleKeyInfo name = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine("You pressed {0}", name.KeyChar);

if(name.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Space key was pressed");
}
```